# Каким образом подсоединить горизонтальное recyclerView в вертикальный recyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Нужно создать вертикальный список элементов с одним элементом, в котором элементым в горизонтальном положении. Поэтому нужно использовать два recyclerViewAdapter, но проблема в не понимании этого. Каким образом это делается? 
Уже есть вертикальный adapter

```
public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

@NonNull
private List<BaseProductsItem> baseProductsItems;
@Nullable
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public ProductsAdapter(@NonNull List<BaseProductsItem> baseProductsItems,
                       @Nullable OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.baseProductsItems = baseProductsItems;
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType){
        case ProductsType.TITLE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_title_products, parent, false);
            return new TitleVH(view);
        case ProductsType.DEPOSIT:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_deposits_products, parent, false);
            return new DepositVH(view);
        case ProductsType.CREDIT:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_credits_products, parent, false);
            return new CreditVH(view);
        case ProductsType.DEBIT_CARD:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_debitcards_products, parent, false);
            return new DebitCardVH(view);
        case ProductsType.CREDIT_CARD:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_creditcards_products, parent, false);
            return new CreditCardVH(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    BaseProductsItem item = baseProductsItems.get(position);
    if (item instanceof TitleProductsItem) {
        TitleVH titleVH = (TitleVH) holder;
        TitleProductsItem titleItem = (TitleProductsItem) item;
        titleVH.tvTitle.setText(null);
    } else if (item instanceof DepositsProductsItem) {
        DepositVH depositVH = (DepositVH) holder;
        DepositsProductsItem depositItem = (DepositsProductsItem) item;
        depositVH.tvNameDeposits.setText(null);
        depositVH.tvOpenedDeposits.setText(null);
        depositVH.tvAmountDeposits.setText(null);
    } else if (item instanceof CreditsProductsItem) {
        CreditVH creditVH = (CreditVH) holder;
        CreditsProductsItem creditItem = (CreditsProductsItem) item;
        creditVH.tvNameCredits.setText(null);
        creditVH.tvNextPaymentDateCredits.setText(null);
        creditVH.tvNextPaymentAmountCredits.setText(null);
        creditVH.tvAmountCredits.setText(null);
    } else if (item instanceof DebitCardsProductsItem) {
        DebitCardVH debitCardVH = (DebitCardVH) holder;
        DebitCardsProductsItem cardItem = (DebitCardsProductsItem) item;
        debitCardVH.tvDebitCardsNumber.setText(null);
        debitCardVH.tvDebitCardsName.setText(null);
        debitCardVH.tvDebitCardsAmount.setText(null);
    } else if (item instanceof CreditCardsProductsItem) {
        CreditCardVH creditCardVH = (CreditCardVH) holder;
        CreditCardsProductsItem cardItem = (CreditCardsProductsItem) item;
        creditCardVH.tvCreditCardsNumber.setText(null);
        creditCardVH.tvCreditCardsName.setText(null);
        creditCardVH.tvCreditCardsAmount.setText(null);
    }
}

public static class TitleVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvTitle) TextView tvTitle;

    public TitleVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

public static class AccountVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public AccountVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

public static class DepositVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvNameDeposits) TextView tvNameDeposits;

    @BindView(R.id.tvOpenedDeposits) TextView tvOpenedDeposits;

    @BindView(R.id.tvAmountDeposits) TextView tvAmountDeposits;

    public DepositVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

public static class CreditVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvNameCredits) TextView tvNameCredits;

    @BindView(R.id.tvNextPaymentDateCredits) TextView tvNextPaymentDateCredits;

    @BindView(R.id.tvNextPaymentAmountCredits) TextView tvNextPaymentAmountCredits;

    @BindView(R.id.tvAmountCredits) TextView tvAmountCredits;

    public CreditVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

public static class DebitCardVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvDebitCardsName) TextView tvDebitCardsName;

    @BindView(R.id.tvDebitCardsNumber) TextView tvDebitCardsNumber;

    @BindView(R.id.tvDebitCardsAmount) TextView tvDebitCardsAmount;

    public DebitCardVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

public static class CreditCardVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvCreditCardsName) TextView tvCreditCardsName;

    @BindView(R.id.tvCreditCardsNumber) TextView tvCreditCardsNumber;

    @BindView(R.id.tvCreditCardsAmount) TextView tvCreditCardsAmount;

    public CreditCardVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return baseProductsItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    BaseProductsItem item = baseProductsItems.get(position);
    if (item instanceof DepositsProductsItem)
        return ProductsType.DEPOSIT;
    else if (item instanceof CreditsProductsItem)
        return ProductsType.CREDIT;
    else if (item instanceof DebitCardsProductsItem)
        return ProductsType.DEBIT_CARD;
    else if (item instanceof CreditCardsProductsItem)
        return ProductsType.CREDIT_CARD;
    else if (item instanceof TitleProductsItem)
        return ProductsType.TITLE;
    else return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитал ваш код, надеюсь это `stackoverflow` сжал его в один файл) Все так же, как и раньше, но теперь во `ViewHolder` инициализирован `RecyclerView`. Для него вы создаете новый адаптер и новый вьюхолдер. Такая модель с легкостью работает и живет, если данные внутри `RecyclerView` не кликабельны, т.е. просто для отображения. Другой вопрос, когда вам нужно обрабатывать клики по по внутреннему RecyclerView, с изменением общих данных. Отсюда у вас два путя: либо хранить адаптеры для каждого внутреннего `RecyclerView`, либо вытягивать данные из `ViewHodler-a`.

Вариант второй - это реализовать внутренний RecyclerView в отдельной фрагменте. Тогда вы сможете полностью разделить логику двух RecyclerView, но это опять-таки все зависит от задачи.

Первый вариант я реализовывал для кастомного календаря, где месяцы скрлились горизонтально, а внутренний `RecyclerView` был месяцем с днями.